# Migrate to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to migrate an existing ASP.NET MVC3 project using the standard (webforms-like) template engine to Razor? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.

Rename your `*.aspx` to `*.cshtml`. Firstpay attention to control directives, for example

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.TheModel>`

now becomes

`@model MvcApplication1.Models.TheModel`

Now examine your views carefully and replace all tags to razor-style tags (`<% %>` -> `@`)

Note that you don't have to migrate all your views - it's perfectly legal to mix the two view engines in a single MVC application so you can plan your migration over time.